# .Net 6 WEB API : Getting a null object when I try to display it

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 objects that are connected to each other using FK.

Models:

```
 public class Category
    {
        public Category() => Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }


 
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = null!;
        [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

When I want to access **product.Category.Name** I get Category Null:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Hello","description":"1","categoryId":1,"price":10,"photoUrl":"111","category":null},
```

I think the problem here is because I use AutoMammper and add 2 more DTO objects:

DTO:

```
public class CategoryDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    
  public class ProductDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

And the data I presented here I added as SeedData in DbContext like this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasData(
                    new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Hello", Description = "1", PhotoUrl = "111", Price = 10, CategoryId = 1 },
                    new Product { Id = 2, Name = "World", Description = "2", PhotoUrl = "111", Price = 20, CategoryId = 2 }
                );

            });
```

Pull Method:

Repo:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            return _context.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IQueryable<Product>> GetProducts()
        {
            var products = _productRepository.GetProducts();
            if (products == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(products);
        }
```

Comment: Where do you create the `Category` entities? Also, are you meaning to use lazy loading?

Comment: So first things first, do you actually have category records in the DB with the corresponding ID's (1, 2)?

Comment: OK, lets try disabling lazy loading. Remove the `virtual` keyword from your navigation property.

Comment: Also, can you show the LINQ expression you're using to pull the records from the DB.

Comment: I want to see the code you're using when querying your DB context. So, I'm assuming it looks something this: `await context.Products.ToListAsync();`

Comment: @WBuck I added it to my post

Comment: OK, can you change your query to the following: `_context.Products.Include(e => e.Category).OrderBy(x => x.Name);`

Comment: @WBuck I still get null but I think that because I didn't add a Category Object field in DBCONTEXT then I get null there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Include()` method to specify related data to be included in query results. Please refer to this code:

```
var result = dbContext.products.Include(x=>x.Category).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Then you can see the properties of Category have been queried together.

[image]

More details you can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager).